# Uninstall WM DRM Active-X control

Tags: activex, uninstallation, drm

I am using WM DRM to protect content.  Licenses for the content are issued through a web page (lauched from within Windows Media Player) using an embedded active-X control with the following Id.

```
clsid:A9FC132B-096D-460B-B7D5-1DB0FAE0C062
```

Obviously, not everyone has access/permission to install the Active-X control so there is a separate process for people in such a position.  When the page first opens it detect if the Active-X control is installed and presents the appropriate option to the user. (THe embedded browser control prompts to install the Active-X control if not already done.)

The issue I have is, having previously allowed installation of the Active-X control I can now find no way to uninstall the control.  I want to be able to uninstall it to make it simpler to test both forms of license delivery.

The control is not listed in the installed add-ons for Internet Explorer, nor in the 'add or remove programs' list (including updates & windows components).  There is an entry for the CLSID in the registry (HKLM\CLSID{A9FC132B-096D-460B-B7D5-1DB0FAE0C062}) but I'm not sure about how to use this to "uninstall" it.

How can I uninstall this Active-X control?

Answer (score 0):

If the control is a dll, this might work:

```
regsvr32 drmdllname.dll /u
```